# VBScript: How to change variable value by calling another script file?

Tags: vbscript

This is how I'm passing arguments **between files** these days.

1.vbs:

```
Dim MyVar

'1) Assigning some value to MyVar.
MyVar = "foo"

'2) Passing MyVar to 2.vbs.
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run _
Chr(34) & "C:" & "\2.vbs" & _
Chr(34) & " " & Chr(34) & MyVar & Chr(34), _
1, True

'4) End point.
MsgBox MyVar
```

2.vbs:

```
    If _
    WScript.Arguments.Count > 0 _
    Then
    Call MySub( _
    WScript.Arguments(0))
    End If

Sub MySub(MyVar)

'3) Doing some work with MyVar.
MyVar = "bar"

End Sub
```

So, if all code was in 1 single file, and 
if I had to use `Call MySub` instead of `CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run` 
— i'd successfully changed `MyVar` from `"foo"` to `"bar"`, 
and got the latter on `MsgBox`.

Yet, sometimes I really want to work with `MyVar` in another file, 
and be able to get it back (to the **already running** first file) with changes.

I just don't know how to do that properly.

Comment: On the second thought, the better and elegant way to implement this is probably to make 1 big file with all Subs I need; add some description to it (or smth, to ease the navigation), and then just `CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run` this big file with specific arguments from smaller one-line files, "fixed" for any situation.

Comment: And by "this" (the initial problem to solve) I mean, like.. having all essential lines of code written and reachable, and not having to rewrite them over and over again.

Comment: [Here](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/13437/i-need-side-menus-to-navigate-huge-text-files/5) is a basic idea of navigation in big text file via Notepad++. One could use some symbols to mark "the chapters" (or Subs really); and then use some custom script to collect all lines having these symbols to the "chapter-list" file.

Comment: I just put everything in one file broken into plenty of subs and functions, but some people like to use `ExecutGlobal` to make a kind of `include` like [this example](https://ctovswild.com/2015/07/16/adventures-in-vbscript-including-code-from-other-files).

Comment: NotePad++ is a good editor, but you may be able to work more effectively using [VBSEdit](https://www.vbsedit.com) which is a complete VBScript IDE.

Comment: @LesFerch yeah, that last one seems perfect due to debugging feature inbuilt. Haven't been coding for a while now, almost forgot about that :) Thank you!

Comment: I also thought to use Notepad++ as above to *write* code, and then may be debug it elsewhere; like in VBSEdit, or VSCode (since the latter supports and debugs many languages, after a little plugging); I should really look into VSCode though, as possibly one ultimate workspace.

Comment: Having tried them all, I would say you'd be most productive using VBSEdit entirely for VBScript. IMO, it's easily worth the small lifetime license price.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1:**
keep the files as they are, and add an echo at the end of your sub:

2.vbs:

```
'(...)
'3) Doing some work with MyVar.
MyVar = "bar"
Wscript.Echo(MyVar)
'(...)
```

1.vbs

Read the output by changing the method "**.Run**" to "**.Exec**"

```
'(...)
'2) Passing MyVar to 2.vbs.
set oShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
set Exe = oShell.Exec("cmd /c 2.vbs """&MyVar&""" ")
MyVar = Exe.StdOut.ReadAll
'(...)
'4) End point.
MsgBox MyVar
```

**Option 2:**
Using the "**2.vbs**" file as a function library and changing the **sub** to function:

1.vbs

```
'Put the import statements at the top of 1.vbs code for easier readability.
Import "2.vbs"
'(...)
MyVar = MyFunction(MyVar)
```

2.vbs

```
Function MyFunction(MyVar)
'3) Doing some work with MyVar.
MyFunction = "bar"
end Function
```

Comment: Never heard of `Import` before; gotta look into it, thank you!